# How to map Grails domain object to a specific mongodb table name

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I've setup a simple grails app looking at a mongodb.

My domain object looks like this:

```
class GoogleSearch {
    String _id;
    String id;
    String query;
    String site;
    Object results;
    Date date;

    static mapping = {
        table 'google_searches'
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

However when I run the grails app up, it keeps reading/writing to a table named "googleSearch"

Does anyone know how I can override this default naming?  Is it a gorm/mongodb thing?

Cheers

Comment: Which grails version are you using ? Mapping table name only supports from Grails 2.2 and above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basics of MongoDB. There is no concept of `table`. It is always `collections`. :)
Refer mapping as `collection 'google_searches'`.

For more details you can refer [Grails MongoDB](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html) plugin.